# How do i start to learn asm (gas)?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I found "hello world" and wrote it. 
    nano hello.s

this code

```
.data
msg:
.string  "Hello, world!\n"
len = . - msg
.text
global _start
_start:
    movl    $len,%edx
    movl    $msg,%ecx
    movl    $1,%ebx
    movl    $4,%eax
    int     $0x80
    movl    $0,%ebx
    movl    $1,%eax
    int     $0x80
```

I've done `as -o hello.o hello.s`
I've given an error

```
hello.s:6: Error: no such instruction: global _start

delete global _start.
```

I've done

```
ld -s -o hello.o hello*

error 

ld: hello: No such file: No such file or directory
```

Where am I mistaking?

p/s debian, amd64.

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are asking. You did run the assembler when you got the error about "global _start". You should look in the manual for the assembler to see what is wrong about that line. Maybe its not supposed to have a space or maybe global needs a <dot> "." in front.

Comment: Use also the `gcc` compiler, and look  inside its generated assembly code, e.g. `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S file.c` then look inside `file.s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.globl _start` or `.global _start`.

You may try ununderscored `start` in case you run into a problem with the entry point.

Finally, if you're making a 64-bit executable, you probably need to use a different system call interface, not `int 0x80` but `syscall`. More on that [here](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/).

Comment: Furthermore... `ld -o hello hello.o` the `-o` switch specifies the output filename, `hello.o` is the file ld is working on. To get 32-bit code from a 64-bit ld, `-m elf_i386`. The old `int 0x80` system calls will work in 64-bit code, but it isn't right. `push reg32` will not work in 64-bit code!